# How close to, or how far from, copyright violation is the movie "Gattaca"?

Tags: copyright, derivative-work

In 1942 a novel appeared: *Beyond This Horizon* by Robert Heinlein.

- The setting is a future time when it has become standard that people's genes are chosen from among their parents' genes by doctors, who try to pick the best among those available, but are forbidden to add any new genes not present in the parents.
- Those whose genes are chosen the old-fashioned way are looked down upon as inferior people.

In 1997 the movie *Gattaca* appeared.

- The setting is a future time when it has become standard that people's genes are chosen from among their parents' genes by doctors, who try to pick the best among those available, but are forbidden to add any new genes not present in the parents.
- Those whose genes are chosen the old-fashioned way are looked down upon as inferior people.

In 1953 the novel *Starman Jones*, also by Robert Heinlein, appeared.

- The protagonist falsifies his identity and work record to get a position in the crew of a spacecraft.
- The protagonist has memorized a book on navigation in space.

In *Gattaca*,

- The protagonist falsifies his identity and work record to get a position in the crew of a spacecraft.
- The protagonist has memorized a book on navigation in space.

But the story in *Gattaca* is quite different from those in either of the two Heinlein novels. In *Gattaca*, the spacecraft is on a bold mission of exploration; in *Starman Jones* it is a luxury liner that makes routine voyages carrying passengers and freight.

In *Gattaca* the protagonist is one of those whose genes were chosen the old-fashioned way; in *Beyond This Horizon* he is is one whom the government wants to have many children to continue their eugenics program because he is considered of superior stock. He wishes not to have children because he thinks most humans are naturally unhappy and he would only be sentencing his descendants to unhappy lives. And some of his coevals are so unhappy despite their affluent lifestyle that they want to overthrow the fairly liberal government and replace it with a dictatorship.

Heinlein is not acknowledged in the movie credits.

How much do they need to lift from already published fiction before it becomes a derivative work with obligations to the owner of the copyright on the earlier work?

Comment: I'm sure it would be (persuasively, IMO) argued by the studio lawyers that positive Eugenics is not unique to *Beyond This Horizon*, and that (1) doctors choosing genes is a naturally foreseeable outcome, and (2) the nominally superior oppressing and discriminating against the nominally inferior is as old as humanity.

Answer (score 30):

Under U.S. law (17 U.S. Code § 101 )

> A “derivative work” is a work based upon one or more preexisting works, such as a translation, musical arrangement, dramatization, fictionalization, motion picture version, sound recording, art reproduction, abridgment, condensation, or any other form in which a work may be recast, transformed, or adapted. A work consisting of editorial revisions, annotations, elaborations, or other modifications which, as a whole, represent an original work of authorship, is a “derivative work.”

But probably, focusing on this definition doesn't get to the heart of the question you seem to be asking.   A more important matter becomes *what protections does a copyright **exclude**?*  This is covered in § 102 (b), which says:

> In no case does copyright protection for an original work of authorship extend to any idea, procedure, process, system, method of operation, concept, principle, or discovery, regardless of the form in which it is described, explained, illustrated, or embodied in such work.

The similarities you describe seem to be more ideas and concepts rather than Heinlein's expression of those ideas. I have looked no closer than the description used in the question, but the movie seems unlikely to have violated a protected right. Others might disagree.

Comment: People skirt much closer to this line all the time. *Fifty Shades of Grey* was literally a *Twilight* fan-fiction with [the serial numbers filed off](https://fanlore.org/wiki/Filing_Off_The_Serial_Numbers). Based on the description in the question, this is not even remotely a close call.

Answer (score 21):

I have read the Heinlein books you cite many times, and seen the movie *Gattaca* once. I do not think *Gattaca* is a derivative work of either or both novels. The concept of faking an identity in order to get a desired job is a very common trope, both in SF and in general literature. The kind of faking done in the movie is not very similar to the deception in *Starman Jones*. The overt, pervasive, legal discrimination in the movie is quite unlike the situation in *Beyond This Horizon*. In the novel, "Control Naturals"  (people born without artificial genetic selection) receive a government subsidy, but no one knows who they are unless they choose to make this public. They lack the ability for some jobs (or some of them do), but are perfectly able to do many professional jobs, and one is shown as running his own business. They are not at all limited to menial jobs.

Only the (rather cardboard) villains of the novel plan to discriminate against the control naturals, and they are defeated before they can put these plans into effect. (An insider reveals that they actually plan to wipe out the "naturals".)

Also the major themes of the Social Credit economic system, and the investigation into life after death and reincarnation in BTH are not at all present in the movie.

The question asks:

> How much do they need to lift from already published fiction before it becomes a derivative work with obligations to the owner of the copyright on the earlier work?

There is no clear bright line on this. But in general copyright does not protect ideas or broad themes. A classic plot such as "boy meets girl" or "monster threatens city" is not enough to make the later work derivative of the earlier one.  There must be detailed point-by-point similarities of elements of plot or character for one work to be derivative of another.

For example, the early classic SF movie *Forbidden Planet* has some similarities of concept and tone with the "original" version of the TV series *Star Trek*.  Indeed FP could probably have been rewritten as an episode of ST without drastic changes. But this was not sufficient to make ST a derivative work.

It might be a good rule of thumb to say that if **all** the similarities can be described in a one-page plot summery, they are not enough to make the later work derivative. A better test is that the existence of detailed, point-by-point similarities will often lead to a conclusion that the later work is derivative.

Comment: On the _Forbidden Planet_ note -- Gene Roddenberry told his biographer that _Forbidden Planet_ was indeed one of his inspirations for _Star Trek_. _Forbidden Planet_ itself is, of course, seen as a modern adaptation of Shakespeare's _The Tempest_. There are also some lengthy threads elsewhere on Stack discussing Heinlein's apparent 19th-century inspirations for _Starman Jones_ and whether it drew from an actual incident on a sailing vessel.

Comment: You say control naturals in _Beyond This Horizon_ "are not at all limited to menial jobs", but I think the same is true of _Gattaca_. The protagonist was so limited only because he was considered at risk for a heart disease.

Comment: If you've read _Starman Jones_ many times, can you tell me whether you noticed that the law that is applied to the protagonist in Chapter 20 was explicitly stated more than a dozen chapters earlier? (But don't tell people here what it was; that would be a spoiler.)

Comment: @Michael I think it is first mentioned in chpter 6 ("Spaceman" Jones) where there is a discussion of the organization of star-ships in that universe.  Frankly I don't think there is much need to worry about spoilers for a book first published in 1953, rarely out of print since, and probably one of the top 50 or 100 best known works of SF ever. Further discussion of the book probably belongs on SFF.SE, where it has been mentioned in several threads.

Comment: @DavidSiegel : Just why one should not worry about spoilers I don't know. The fact is that the majority of humans have not read that story.

Comment: @DavidSiegel : Are you a lawyer? Has any specifically lawyer's take on that story been written? Obviously the laws on eminent domain and intestate succession would have changed, but still a lawyer's point of view on some of that might shed some light. (The whole thing about inheritance of guild membership can be accepted without any problems in understanding them, but the parts about property seem problematic.)

Comment: @Michael Hardy  I am not a lawyer, I am a software developer who has long studied law as a hobby. I have not read or heard of any specifically legal analysis of the novel SJ. Given that laws would be likely to change over several hundred years, I don't find anything improbable about the sections dealing with Max's inheritance from his father. Indeed I don't think they would be much out of place in a novel set in the 1950s.

Comment: @Michael Hardy as for spoilers the majority of the human race has not read any story in particular. Yet those likely to be interested in SJ have had many opportunities to do so.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "those likely to be interested in SJ have had many opportunities to do so" That's a very odd statement. You think there are no 15-year-olds who haven't read it but would appreciate it if they did?

Comment: @DavidSiegel : Montgomery knew some speculator was buying farms in the vicinity for a reason, i.e. they knew the government was going to take some land and thought they could get more for it than they paid. This assumes the farmers were more ignorant of the situation than Montgomery was, which is perhaps not completely implausible. But why would the government's payment to Max be held for him it the government took the farm from the speculator who had bought it from Max's mother?

Comment: @DavidSiegel : A rather large number of legal issues are raised, about nearly all of which you can say that some laws will have changed and some won't. Trespass in a tunnel built for trains, impersonating a licensed teamster, the duty to return a library book, bribery, forger, and fraud by which Max got his job, succession to command of the ship when the captain dies, etc. HOWEVER, the BIG thing is when the First Officer reminds everyone that laws remain in force aboard the ship even when it is lost and lands on an unknown planet. That needed to happen in order to make sure that the....

Comment: ....reader understands what is going on four chapters later.

Comment: @Michael "But why would the government's payment to Max be held for him it the government took the farm from the speculator who had bought it from Max's mother?" Sam suggests that Montgomery could not in fact grant a valid deed without Max's signature, so presumably the sale to the speculator never went through. That would be true in many US states under current law. But really this should be a new question here or on the SF stack.

Comment: Although copyright courts are not always bound to follow any sort of logic, I think a good principle for an author to follow would be to focus primarily on tropes which appear in multiple independent works, and blend them in such a way that one's new work isn't much closer to the either of the originals than the originals were to each other.

Answer (score 2):

The example that comes readily to mind of "plot similarity as copyright infringement" is "Fistful of Dollars" being an old-west copy of Kurosawa's "Yojimbo" samurai movie. Reportedly settled for 15%.

But that wasn't a couple of ideas, that approached a scene-by-scene remake.

Legal merits aren't the only possible reasons to settle. Negative publicity and respect for Kurosawa could've played a part.

Also, this was Italians making a movie in Spain that made most of its money in America being sued by a Japanese guy in the mid-60's--the logistics alone are a compelling reason to settle.

Comment: Besides, *Yojimbo* used the plot of Dashiell Hammett's Continental Op novel [*Red Harvest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Harvest) (and possibly also his novel *The Glass Key*). These also formed the basis of David Drake's SF novel *The Sharp End* and of an SF novel by another author *Red Noise*.